# Rspec stubbing results in Mocha errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Not quite sure what's going on here. I'm moving over some code from another project of mine and suddenly the same specs from before are generating errors in the new project.  All the errors appear to revolve around calling the stub method.  Here's an example test:

```
it "retrieves active workers from Redis" do
    @monitor.should_receive(:monitor_running?).and_return(false)
    REDIS.should_receive( :smembers ).with( 'leaderboard-workers' ).and_return( [] )
    @monitor.perform
end
```

This works.  However if I switch the first test line to this:

```
  @monitor.stub(:monitor_running?).and_return(false)
```

I end up with the following error:

```
 1) LeaderboardMonitor#perform retrieves active workers from Redis
 Failure/Error: @monitor.stub(:monitor_running?).and_return(false)
 Mocha::ExpectationError:
   unexpected invocation: #<Mock:0x7fcc18c8bab8>.and_return(false)
   satisfied expectations:
   - allowed any number of times, not yet invoked: #<Mock:0x7fcc18c8bab8>.monitor_running?(any_parameters)
 # ./spec/workers/leaderboards/leaderboard_monitor_spec.rb:58:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm not quite sure what's going on here.  Is this an issue with Mocha overriding the stub method?  How do I work around this?!?!?

Comment: Are you using rspec and mocha in the same project? Maybe this would help? https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-7/docs/mock-framework-integration/mock-with-mocha

Comment: I'm not using mocha however it's a dependency of other gems.  Not using it for my testing though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what version of mocha you are using. Have you tried something like

```
@monitor.expects(:monitor_running?).returns(false).at_least_once
```